# Haskell - How to create data from a list

Tags: haskell

If I have some kind of data structure:

```
data Object = Object { a :: String, b :: String, c :: String }
```

How can I create a function such that it takes a list of strings and creates the object, where the first element is a, second element is b... etc assuming the list is the right size and in the right order>

```
createObject :: [String] -> Object
```

Comment: `\[a,b,c] -> Object a b c`?

Answer (score 6):

You have to define the function explicitly, and it is necessarily a partial function.

```
createObject [x,y,z] = Object x y z
```

Haskell doesn't provide any special syntax for this because the number of cases where it would apply is relatively small.

1. The input list has to have the exact number of elements required by the product type. You could argue that the function could simply ignore elements from a longer list, but you can't return a partially applied `Object`: `Object x y` has type `String -> Object`, not `Object`.

   With dependent types, though, you could define `createObject` to take lists of exactly the right length, somewhat negating this point.
2. The product type is limited to products of the same type. (No list could be used to create something of type `data Foo = Foo {a ::Int, b::String}`, for example.)

---

Update:

Point 1 is a little weak; you could define a total function like

```
createObject (x:y:z:_) = Object x y z
createObject [x,y] = Object x y ""
createObject [x] = Object x "" ""
createObject [] = Object "" "" ""
```

which would ignore extra input items and specify a default value for missing items.

Comment: It isn't _necessarily_ partial but that is the most obvious solution.  He could also define `createObject _ = Object "" "" ""` or other variants.

Comment: Good point. That affects my point #1 as well; I'll think about how to best revise my answer.